# Is it possible to export all recorded events together in AWS Pinpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-pinpoint

I am tracking user behaviour within my mobile react-native application. My configurations are working and I am recording an event like this:

```
await Analytics.record({
  name: "TestEvent",
  attributes: {
    user: user,
    attr: "test",
  },
});
```

The events are successfully recorded and I can see them in the pinpoint dashboard.

The problem I am facing now is that I can only download the CSV file of a single event. Also, it seems to be necessary to filter for each individual attribute recorded to get a set of csv files belonging to a single event.

This seems to be very cumbersome. I would like to be able to download all records at once.
Is this possible within AWS Pinpoint? Additionally I tried to set up the Amazon Kinesis Data Stream - but there I can only access GET/PUT records etc. pp. but not the recorded event(-type)s.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have exactly the same problem, I've gone as far as setting all up in GTM...